# ARM Cortex-M3 NVIC config with FreeRTOS

Tags: interrupt, freertos, cortex-m

I'm working on a legacy projected using FreeRTOS v7.3.0 on an STM32F205 Cortex-M3, built with IAR EWARM v6.70.

My system intermittently lands in the hard fault exception handler, and/or watchdog resets.

I have tracked down some issues with the NVIC config:

1. NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_1) was used instead of NVIC_PriorityGroup_4.  NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig() is from STM StdPeriph Driver Lib v1.1.0.
2. Not all app isr priorities were below configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY.  Some of the isrs are big, so rather than verifying no FreeRTOS API calls, I made sure all app isr priorities are a lower priority (higher priority number) than the current configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY setting of 5.

These fixes are in test, but being an intermittent problem, are there any other NVIC/interrupt related gotchas with FreeRTOS/Cortex-M3 that I should be aware of?

Thanks,

-Rob

Comment: The argument to the priority group config in the STM32 headers is the exact opposite to the ARM headers (what ST call 0 ARM call 4, and vice versa).  FreeRTOS requires that all priority bits are used for pre-emption, no grouping allowed, check you have it that way around.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I directly checked the AIRCR.PRIGROUP in the debugger.  With Group4 (the fix) I see 0x3, which ST doc PM0056 indicates 16 group priorities, non sub priorities.  Group1 (legacy) showed 0x6, which indicates 2 group priorities, 8 sub priorities.